# implementing a many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, many-to-many, mysql-workbench

I am planning on creating a database to track teams and players in a soccer league. The stats I wish to track are as follows...

goals scored/conceded(gk), assists, minutes played, cards received and leading scorers.

As well as overall standings and fixtures and results. I have created an ER diagram and I think I have all the required tables but have some m:n relationships which I know shouldn't exist so am hoping my relationships are correct

**Update**
updated er diagram 
[image]

I may or may not include the second tire of this league otherwise I don't think I actually need the league table.

will it cause me any problems if i implement it as is. i am not sure if it is ok to have 2 cols in the `fixtures` table that are referencing one column from the `teams` table. And my `goals_scored` table has the same two fk's as my `player_match` table.

Am I anywhere near the right track? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to have two columns of a table reference the same column of another table.  The fixtures table has a home_team and an away_team column, each has a different meaning, but point to the same type of entity.

I think your goals scored table would be better if it referenced the player_match table instead of the players table as the only players it can reference are the ones in who have played in the fixture.

You also need to consider how you are going to extract the data from the tables as you are duplicated the goals_scored and goals_conceded columns across three tables.  It would help your data integrity if those values where store once, say on the goals_scored table, and calculated by your query when extracting the data.

Comment: thanks. in that case would you also recommend that i remove the last 8 cols from `teams` as they can be calculated from `fixtures`

Comment: Yes.  Storing the same data in multiple places makes the DB harder to maintain. If you change your db structure later, or change how it's updated, you have to

Comment: ensure all your updates are consistent.  Having the data store in one place means that any changes to that data only happen in that one place. (Sorry for broken comment - still getting used to the StackOverflow UI)